# MVC Button element with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I pass parameters to a controller action method with a button element?

This is not a form submit, I just want a button that is going to take you to another page, but the action method requires parameters.

I currently have:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick='window.location = "@Url.Action("Index", "ReviewPendingApprovals", new object[] { Model.QuoteGuid })";'>
```

However, this results in empty HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick='window.location = "";'>
```

what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Its better to do using jquery, you can write the script is shared_layout file.. or in applayout file.. 

If you want to add data you can use data attributes using jquery. its Easy to retrieve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's best to use an HTML helper for this.

```
@Html.ActionLink(
  "ButtonText", 
  "Index",                         // controller action
  "ReviewPendingApprovals",        // controller
  new { Model.QuoteGuid },         // action parameters aka route values
  new { @class = "btn btn-info" }) // html attributes
```

Comment: This is the route I went with.   An ActionLink combined with CSS to fake it to look like a button.

Comment: I just applied Bootstrap styles to it .. in the format     @Html.ActionLink("Something",
        "Index", "TheController",
        new { param1 = Model.Param1 }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }).

Answer (score 3):

RIGHT ANSWER HERE:
You did two things wrong: you didn't mark the `onClick` delegate as an `href`, and you didn't map the argument/route values to any parameter (but that didn't cause the render HTML markup to be blank)

I prefer to use input tags, but you **can** use a button tag

Here's what your solution should look like using HTML:

```
< input type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick='window.location.**href** = "@Url.Action("Index", "ReviewPendingApprovals", new { **someParamHere** = Model.QuoteGuid })";'/>
```

Comment: You can omit the semicolon -- not needed now

Answer (score 1):

I never tried to do it directly from a button, but when I use the controller to do it, it looks something like:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", new { param1 = param1_value, param2 = param2_value });
```

so I suggest you try this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick='window.location = "@Url.Action("Index", "ReviewPendingApprovals", new object[] { object_name = Model.QuoteGuid })";'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the URL Scheme parameter to Url.Action:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick='window.location = "@Url.Action("Index", "ReviewPendingApprovals", new object[] { Model.QuoteGuid },  this.Request.Url.Scheme)";'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could code like this:

```
 $('.btn-info').click(function (e) {





                var url='@Url.Action("Index", "ReviewPendingApprovals",new { id= Model.QuoteGuid })';

                window.location=url;

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery instead of onclick event:

> $('button').click(function(){
>      winodw.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action","Controller",new{parameter name =     value})';
>   });

Comment: typo "winodw", should be "window". I actually copied your code and it was failing.